# Tagging identification questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Since we accept some questions about [species identification](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/3143), I wonder how we should tag these.

For [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/8194/3143) question I created the [animal-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification), but I am unsure if this is a senseful thing to do. Should we have a tag [identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) or rather two, [animal-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification) and [plant-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-identification)? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags are called 'identify-this' tags, so I would suggest following the same naming conventions as the rest of the network:

[identify-this-animal](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-animal) [identify-this-plant](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-plant)

This avoids any surprises when folks folks visit here from other sites. Plus, folks can easily 'favorite' or 'ignore' these tags by entering, `Ignored Tags: [identify-this-*]`.

This naming convention can also be expanded to include *other* areas of identification as needed:

[identify-this-track](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-track) [identify-this-scat](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-scat), etc, etc.