# Tree care - better here or Gardening?

Tags: discussion, scope

I live in an area recently devastated by the emerald ash borer.  I and several of my neighbors were forced to spend a lot of money to take down a lot of trees, before they came down on their own jeopardizing our homes.

I lost three trees (and gained 2.5 cords of firewood I can never sell) but one of the three had been far healthier than the other before, and its roots have been putting out fresh saplings.

My question will be about caring for this tree, keeping EAB away from it, helping it grow around the stump of its predecessor, and so on.

I have read this: [What questions about flora are in scope?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/9109) which seems to suggest I should go to Gardening and not here, but it is less than definitive.  I'll ask the question wherever the consensus indicates.

Comment: I think it would be better answered in Gardening, but @Sue is on both, and I would follow her advice.

Comment: Done (on gardening, not here): http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/29765/13391

Comment: @Sue,  Aw, shucks, you're making me blush.  Anyway, my primary domains are SO, WB, and ELU, but I pop my nose in a few other SE now and then, when I feel the need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be off topic here. It does look like it would fit in with Gardening's scope, and I see other questions there that are similar so I'd suggest asking there.